# Most efficient way to count primeomega(n)=4?

Tags: number-theory, summation, computational-complexity, computational-mathematics, computational-number-theory

**Problem:**

Given natural number N, count $\sum_{k\le N} [{\omega(k)=4}]$

[This](https://oeis.org/A033993) is the sequence of $\omega(k)=4$, we don't need to generate the sequence. Given a $N$, we need to know number of numbers in the sequence that are less than or equal to $N$.

You can assume $O(n^{2/3})$ memory is available.

**Clarification:**

[primeomega](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime_omega_function)(n) or $\omega(n)$ denotes count of number of distinct prime factors of a natural number $n$. For example $\omega(12)=2$ as its factors are {2,2,3} since we consider only distinct prime factors; whereas $\omega(6)=2$ as well as $\omega(36)=2$ . I am interested in counting $\sum \omega(i)= SomeValue$, to be particular $SomeValue \ge 4$  since smaller $SomeValue$ seems trivial.

**My Thoughts:**

The most brute force approach is to visit each number and factorise spending time complexity of $O(N.N^{1/4})=O(N^{5/4})$. Obviously that won't cut it. I need a sublinear algo.

I am thinking on lines of expressing one omega's recurrence in terms of another, something like: $f(N=100,w=4) = K*f(N=100/prime_{i},w=3)$ in a way it can be expressed in something similar to [Legendre's prime counting](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/LegendresFormula.html) function .
For that sieving primes till $N^{1/2}$ might be necessary. My ideas are far from concrete, needs lot of refinement.

**To summarise:**

- Expected Time Complexity: $O(n^{3/4})$ or better
- Expected Space Complexity: $O(n^{2/3})$ or better

Comment: You don’t need to factorise completely in most cases to find there are four or fewer prime factors. If there are no factors <= N^(1/5) then there can’t be more than four prime factors.

Comment: @gnasher729  yes small optimization, improving the brute force from $N^{5/4}$ to $N^{6/5}$ . factorization isn't going to give us a sublinear algo.

Comment: @sibillalazzerini FYI, basically the same question has been asked at [Counting numbers smaller than $N$ with exactly $k$ *distinct* prime factors](/q/4044791) (found in the "Related" section on the RHS), but it doesn't specify any particular required maximum time or space complexity. Nonetheless, you may find some of the comments and answers there to be helpful to you.

Comment: @JohnOmielan I see. actually I realised that but I am not sure about the correctness of that solution, even though time complexity wise it(1st answer) is at par with my expectations. if you understand it would be great if you could reproduce it in your own words.

Comment: You're using the word "series", but those are not series, they are **sequences**.

Comment: @jjagmath Thanks for pointing out, updated. Do let me know if you have any ideas. I still don't fully understand the linked answers. So feel free to give alternative ideas if you have any.